# PropTypes not available after applying HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I recently built a components library but when I import my components my IDE doesn't show autocomplete props like other components do (based on propTypes) :

[image: Desired behavior]

In my library, all components are exported with a HOC and I found out that by removing the HOC the props are now available in auto complete. Here's my HOC :

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import hoistNonReactStatics from 'hoist-non-react-statics'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { defaultTheme } from '../styles/defaultTheme'

const withTheme = (WrappedComponent) => {
  const ThemeContext = React.createContext(defaultTheme)

  const Enhance = (props) => {
    const { _reactThemeProviderForwardedRef, ...rest } = props

    return (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {(theme) => (
          <WrappedComponent
            {...rest}
            theme={theme}
            ref={_reactThemeProviderForwardedRef}
          />
        )}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    )
  }

  Enhance.propTypes = {
    _reactThemeProviderForwardedRef: PropTypes.any,
    ...WrappedComponent.propTypes,
  }

  const ResultComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <Enhance {...props} _reactThemeProviderForwardedRef={ref} />
  ))

  ResultComponent.displayName = `withTheme(${
    WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name
  })`

  return hoistNonReactStatics(ResultComponent, WrappedComponent)
}

export default withTheme
```

I'm probably doing something wrong in my `withTheme` but I cannot find out what.

Here is one of the components :

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Text, StyleSheet, TextPropTypes } from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { buildStyleSheet } from '../util/style-helpers'
import { withTheme } from '../core/theming'

const CustomText = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { children, className = '', style, theme, ...others } = props
  const customStyle = buildStyleSheet(className, 'text', theme)

  return (
    <Text
      ref={ref}
      style={StyleSheet.flatten([customStyle, style])}
      {...others}
    >
      {children}
    </Text>
  )
})

const propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.any,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  ...TextPropTypes,
}

CustomText.displayName = 'CustomText'
CustomText.propTypes = propTypes

export default withTheme(CustomText)
```

Comment: Maybe TypeScript can help you. I feel like PropTypes is not very troublesome at times and if you'd like a type system, try TS